# using udptunnel with openvpn

Tags: tunneling

I'm trying to tunnel `openvpn` traffic (UDP protocol) over a firewall using `udptunnel`
I can't use `openvpn` itself on TCP protocol.
On the server I'm running `udptunnel` like this:

```
udptunnel -s 9999 127.0.0.1/1196
```

but I'm getting `setup_udp_recv: bind: Address already in use` because openvpn is listening on this UDP port.
How should I run `udptunnel` on server to forward tunneled openvpn's traffic from port 9999 TCP over same server's 1196 UDP?

Answer (score 0):

You don't bind to the target port, you bind to any other port on the local interface and specify the target port when connecting to the client, like so:

Server:

```
udptunnel -s 443 127.0.0.1/51820
```

Where 443 is the TCP port to listen on and 51820 is a randomly chosen port.

Client

```
udptunnel -c 12.34.56.78/443 127.0.0.1 1196
```

Where 12.34.56.78 is the server's public IP address and 1196 is the target UDP port where your desired service is listening on.

Comment: Note: I suspect this answer might come a tiny bit late for OP, but this page comes out on top of search results for similar problems